# JNLP sin cache no ejecuta app JavaFX

Tags: java, c#, javafx, webforms, jnlp

Tengo aun aplicación web en c# (*webforms*) que construye un **jnlp** para que en el lado del cliente se pueda ejecutar una app **javaFX**. Al realizar pruebas con el cache de java habilitado, la aplicación corre normalmente (*vale aclarar que la aplicacion tiene un jar principal y un jar que es el pre-loader*). Cuando deshabilitamos el cache de java, la aplicación no se ejecuta y en los procesos de windows queda activo un JP2Launcher. Se revisa el log de java Web Start y tenemos lo siguiente:

```
Log started: jue, 15 ago 2019 13:43:22 -0500
Java Web Start 11.211.2.12
Usando versión de JRE
 1.8.0_211-b12 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
network: Created version ID: 1.5.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.211
network: Created version ID: 1.8
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.211
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@cf63f707: 4
basic: XMLParser with _source:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" codebase="http://1.1.1.1/" href="mK4IQSImVB4AQYNlBe1ATest.jnlp">
<information>
<title>Contoso Online Java</title>
<vendor>Contoso S.A.</vendor>
<homepage href="http://1.1.1.1/jars"/>
</information>
<security>
<all-permissions/>
</security>
<resources>
<j2se version="1.7+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
<jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.2.2+"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcmail-jdk15on-1.47.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcpkix-jdk13-161.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/iText-5.0.6.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/axis.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/javax.wsdl_1.6.2.v201005080631.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/fontawesomefx-8.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/org.apache.commons.logging_1.0.4.v201005080501.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/jaxrpc.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/saaj.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/commons-discovery-0.2.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/crossFunctionalities.jar"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestPreLoader.jar" download="progress"/>
<jar href="http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestApp.jar" download="eager" main="true"/>
</resources>
<applet-desc width="1024" height="768" main-class="Test.Main" name="TestApp"/>
<jfx:javafx-desc documentBase="http://1.1.1.1/" name="TestApp" main-class="Test.Main" preloader-class="Test.TestPreLoader">
    <fx:param name="posX" value="180" />
    <fx:param name="posY" value="210" />
    <fx:param name="minpasswordlength" value="4" />
</jfx:javafx-desc>
<update check="background" policy="always"/>
</jnlp>
temp: returning LaunchDesc from XMLFormat.parse():
network: LaunchDownload: concurrent downloads from LD: 4
network: Total size to download: -1
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcpkix-jdk13-161.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestPreLoader.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcmail-jdk15on-1.47.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://1.1.1.1:80 con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://1.1.1.1:80 con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://1.1.1.1:80 con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/bcprov-jdk14-138.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://1.1.1.1:80 con proxy=DIRECT
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@cf63f707: 5
network: ResponseCode de http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar: 200
network: Codificación de http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar: null
network: Respuesta de servidor: (length: 424113, lastModified: Fri Jul 19 07:14:48 COT 2019, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
network: Descargando recurso: http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar
    Content-Lenght: 424.113
    Content-Encoding: null
network: Conectando http://ocsp.usertrust.com/ con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://ocsp.usertrust.com:80 con proxy=DIRECT
security: OCSP Response: GOOD
network: Conectando http://ocsp.sectigo.com/ con proxy=DIRECT
network: Conectando socket://ocsp.sectigo.com:80 con proxy=DIRECT
security: OCSP Response: GOOD
security: Validación de certificado correcta mediante OCSP/CRL
security: Guardando certificados en el almacén de certificados de la sesión de despliegue
security: Certificados guardados en el almacén de certificados de la sesión de despliegue
security: Guardando certificados en el almacén de certificados de la sesión de despliegue
security: Certificados guardados en el almacén de certificados de la sesión de despliegue
security: Verifying permission attribute in main jar: http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestApp.jar
security: Security check for progress jars: allSigned=true
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: Test.TestPreLoader: try again ..
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.getPermissions()
security: Grant connect perm for http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestApp.jar : java.security.Permissions@7684f335 (
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://1.1.1.1:80/-" "*:*")
 ("java.net.URLPermission" "http://1.1.1.1:80" "*:*")
)

basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.getPermissions CeilingPolicy allPerms
security: No hay información de registro de hora disponible
security: JAVAWS AppPolicy Permission requested for: http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/TestApp.jar
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.getPermissions() X
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid preloader-class or progress-class.
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.createCustomProgress(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.instantiatePreloader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.progress.PreloaderDelegate.doInitPreloader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.progress.PreloaderDelegate.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.progress.PreloaderDelegate$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: URL http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar escrita en archivo C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache4808366296692832725.tmp
security: blacklist: check contains KDfOQjNFG8HepgfevU38XNEKBHxghmt8FbM4anLH11w=, state now IN_MEMORY
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
security: No se ha encontrado el archivo de la lista de bibliotecas de confianza
security: blacklist: check contains KDfOQjNFG8HepgfevU38XNEKBHxghmt8FbM4anLH11w=, state now IN_MEMORY
security: blacklist: not  found in cache
network: Desconectar conexión con http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar
network: Downloaded http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\jar_cache4808366296692832725.tmp
cache: Adding MemoryCache entry: http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/log4j-1.2.15.jar
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@69dd3fba: 1
network: Download Progress: jarsDone: 2
network: Conectando http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/axis.jar con proxy=DIRECT
network: ResponseCode de http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/axis.jar: 200
network: Codificación de http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/axis.jar: null
network: Respuesta de servidor: (length: 1685892, lastModified: Tue Jul 23 09:52:34 COT 2019, downloadVersion: null, mimeType: application/java-archive)
network: Descargando recurso: http://1.1.1.1/jarfiles/axis.jar
    Content-Lenght: 1.685.892
    Content-Encoding: null

basic: LaunchDesc.selectJRE( returning selected jre: JREInfo for index 1:
    platform is: 1.8
    product is: 1.8.0_211
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: 
    native platform is: Windows, amd64 [ x86_64, 64bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 1.8.0_211 at: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\lib\ext\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: false

basic: LaunchDesc location: http://1.1.1.1/mK4IQSImVB4AQYNlBe1ATest.jnlp
network: Created version ID: 1.7.0.06
network: Created version ID: 1.0+
network: Created version ID: 8.20
basic: Relaunch because: [current UI toolkit does not match] 
JRESelectException[ jreDesc: null; jvmArgs:  ]
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager$JnlpLaunchState.relaunchApplet(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager$JnlpLaunchState.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.prepareLaunchFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.JNLP2Manager.loadJarFiles(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
cache: registerReference: com.sun.deploy.cache.MemoryCache$CachedResourceReference@cf63f707: 2
basic: Saving session state to C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\session7871781282016484633
network: Created version ID: 1.5.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.211
network: Created version ID: 1.8
network: Created version ID: 1.8.0.211
network: Created version ID: 1.7
basic: Launching new JRE version: JREInfo for index 1:
    platform is: 1.8
    product is: 1.8.0_211
    location is: http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se
    path is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\javaw.exe
    args is: 
    native platform is: Windows, amd64 [ x86_64, 64bit ]
    JavaFX runtime is: JavaFX 1.8.0_211 at: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\lib\ext\
    enabled is: true
    registered is: true
    system is: false

network: Created version ID: 1.7
security: Main class is: com.sun.javaws.Main
basic: secure cmds 0 : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211\bin\jp2launcher.exe
basic: secure cmds 1 : -secure
basic: secure cmds 2 : -javaws
basic: secure cmds 3 : -jre
basic: secure cmds 4 : C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_211
basic: secure cmds 5 : -vma
basic: secure cmds 6 : 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
basic: secure cmds 7 : -ma
basic: secure cmds 8 : LWNvZGViYXNlAGh0dHA6Ly8xMC4yLjIuMTEvAEM6XFVzZXJzXG1sdWdvXEFwcERhdGFcTG9jYWxMb3dcU3VuXEphdmFcRGVwbG95bWVudFxjYWNoZVw2LjBcNDlcN2VjYWY0YjEtM2VmYWI0NzkA
basic: secure cmds 9 : -checkParent
Plugin2Manager calling stopFailed() because of exception during AppContext.dispose()
```

El codigo con el que generamos el **jnlp** es el siguiente:

```
public string loadtestJNLP_FX(bool pIsperfil, int pIdUno, ref System.Web.HttpContext contextoHTTP, string posX, string posY, string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4, ref string param5, string param6 = "", string param7 = "")
    {
        var _serviceUno = FactoryIoC.Container.Resolve<IServiceUnos>();

        pathBase = contextoHTTP.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
        string path = contextoHTTP.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;

        var loadbalancerReceivedSSLRequest = string.Equals(contextoHTTP.Request.Headers["X-Forwarded-Proto"], "https");
        var serverReceivedSSLRequest = contextoHTTP.Request.IsSecureConnection;

        var cabhttp = string.Empty;
        if (loadbalancerReceivedSSLRequest || serverReceivedSSLRequest)
        {
            cabhttp = "https";
        }
        else
        {
            cabhttp = "http";
        }

        string baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UrlWebService"].ToString();

        string template = String.Empty;
        string[] parsemultiParams = param2.Split(';');
        string nombreArchivo = parsemultiParams[1];
        nombreArchivo = nombreArchivo.Replace("+", "").Replace("/", "").Replace("'", "").Replace("`", "").Replace("´", "").Replace("=", "");
        string jnlpName = (nombreArchivo + "test.jnlp");

        try
        {
            template = File.ReadAllText((path + "/jarsFiles/JNLPTemplate_FX.xml"), Encoding.UTF8);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error" + ex.Message);
        }

        string codebase = baseUrl;
        template = template.Replace("#jnlpName", jnlpName);
        template = template.Replace("#codebase", codebase);
        template = template.Replace("#posX", posX);
        template = template.Replace("#posY", posY);
        template = template.Replace("#param1", param1);
        template = template.Replace("#param2", param2);
        template = template.Replace("#param3", param3);
        template = template.Replace("#param4", param4);
        template = template.Replace("#param6", param6);
        template = template.Replace("#minpasswordlength", param7);
        template = template.Replace("#JNLPname", jnlpName);

        if (File.Exists((path + jnlpName)))
        {
            File.Delete((path + jnlpName));
        }

        File.WriteAllText((path + jnlpName), template, Encoding.UTF8);

        return baseUrl + jnlpName;

    }
```

El **jnlp** se construye tomando un template en xml y cambiando unos valores en tiempo de ejcución (este ultimo lo comparto en enlace).

En el siguiente enlace se encuentra completo el log de javaws y el xml de template:

[Log completo y template.xml](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_Ucfck2zY2fVc9f73PxmS9DR3qC723xL?usp=sharing)

Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en ls construcción del **JNLP**:

```
        //Esta linea generaba error en el applet sin cache
        //File.WriteAllText((path + jnlpName), template, Encoding.UTF8);

        using (var jnlpWriter = new StreamWriter(path + jnlpName, true))
        {
            jnlpWriter.WriteLine(template);
        }
```

Se utiliza el StreamWriter y se resuelve el problema.